# Help with my Calathea - strange blue and clear spots?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, prayer-plants

I recently found that my *Calathea* plant has these clear spots on them that are sticky to touch. It has created many translucent spots on the leaves and I am very concerned that it is dying.

[image: these are the blue spots]

[[image: The spots on the other side][2]]

Comment: Which leaves are affected? Lower, older leaves or the new ones as well? Do you see any insects maybe?